# Display a notice in rails after an ajax call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I have a status controller where I render `js` template when a user deletes a status. This is the controller code:

```
def destroy
  @status = Status.where(id: params[:id]).first
  if @status.present?
    make_subject(@status,   Constants::Subject::BREAK)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'deleted' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js { render layout: false }
    end
  end
end
```

In my `destroy.js.erb`, I have:

```
$("#clear_status_<%= @status.id %>").fadeOut();
```

I have a partial which renders flash messages

```
<div id = "notice_wrapper">
  <% if alert %>
    <div class = "alerty">
      <p> <%= alert %> </p>
    </div>
  <% elsif notice %>
    <div class = "notice">
      <p> <%= notice %> </p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Once the status gets deleted successfully I want a notice which informs the user that the status is deleted successfully I want to display that message by rendering this partial.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a way to tell in your response if the delete was successful. And if it was, then show your notice.

For this purpose, I'll create a `@deleted` variable which will be boolean, and will be set to true if delete is successful, otherwise, false.

Following is the controller code:

```
def destroy
  @status = Status.find(params[:id])
  @deleted = false
  if @status.destroy
    @deleted = true
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json
    format.js
  end
end
```

and the `destroy.js.erb` file, you will have something of this sort:

```
<% if @deleted %>
  $(".notice").html(<%= render 'notice_partial' %>)
  <%= escape_javascript(alert("deleted successfully")) %>
<% end %>
$("#clear_status_<%= @status.id %>").fadeOut();
```

Comment: Yeah this worked.. Thanks!.. But instead of alert can we do this using a partial..

Comment: yeah, sure. all you need to do is `render` the partial. so, assuming you have a div with class="notice" and a partial named `notice_partial.html.erb` and you want to render the notice_partial in the notice div, ... I edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hope that is explanatory

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with JQuery. If put your own element instead of `'nav'` where u want to show notice.

```
$('nav').after("<div class='alert alert-success'> Successfully Destroyed </div>");

$("#clear_status_<%= @status.id %>").fadeOut.fadeOut(250, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Also Update your destroy method.

```
def destroy
  @status = Status.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if @status.present?
    make_subject(@status,   Constants::Subject::BREAK)
    respond_to do |format|
      #format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'deleted' } # yr calling it async to destroy. format.html is needless.
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to show the flash in a partial. I have updated my question. Please check. I want to render the message using that partial.